# Error installing nodemon - Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, npm-install, nodemon

I am getting the following error while installing nodemon.

I tried installing with administrator privilege

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18362.778]
(c) 2019 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Windows\system32>npm i nodemon -g
(node:880) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 drain listeners added to [TLSSocket]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
(node:880) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 drain listeners added to [TLSSocket]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
(node:880) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 drain listeners added to [TLSSocket]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
(node:880) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 drain listeners added to [TLSSocket]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
(node:880) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 drain listeners added to [TLSSocket]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
(node:880) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 drain listeners added to [TLSSocket]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
(node:880) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 drain listeners added to [TLSSocket]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
(node:880) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 drain listeners added to [TLSSocket]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
C:\Users\sarif\AppData\Roaming\npm\nodemon -> C:\Users\sarif\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nodemon\bin\nodemon.js

> nodemon@2.0.4 postinstall C:\Users\sarif\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nodemon
> node bin/postinstall || exit 0

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@~2.1.2 (node_modules\nodemon\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

+ nodemon@2.0.4
updated 1 package in 7.774s

C:\Windows\system32>nodemon
'nodemon' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Windows\system32>
```

What is the reason for above error?

How can I fix that?

I am using windows 10 (64 bit)
Nodejs Version: `v12.9.0`
NPM version: `6.10.2`

Comment: Which node-version are you using?

Comment: @eol i am using `v12.9.0` version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this github issue](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/29239#issuecomment-533736550), Node version 12.9.0 has this bug - updating to the latest 12.x version should fix the issue.